# Смена visibility при наведении

Tags: html, css

Такая задача:

При наведении на ссылку `a`, `visibility` линии `hr` должен меняться с `hidden` на `visible`

```css
.portfolio__nav__block a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  margin: 50px 10px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolio__nav__block hr {
  width: 80px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.portfolio__nav__block a:hover .portfolio__nav__block hr {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio__nav__block">
  <a href="#">All projects</a>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: А можно поподробнее?.. эта задача должна быть реализована средствами CSS? Верстка именно такая, как в Вашем примере? (всю доп.информацию пишите, пожалуйста, в непосредственно вопросе)

Comment: Прошу прощения, да, средствами CSS. По поводу верстки - код, что в примере - я так вижу это кнопку. Возможно, это неправильный вариант, хотя ответ уже был дан, и код заработал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.portfolio__nav__block a {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #4a4a4a;
  margin: 50px 10px 0 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.portfolio__nav__block hr {
  width: 80px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #f4511e;
  border: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.portfolio__nav__block a:hover ~ hr {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio__nav__block">
  <a href="#">All projects</a>
  <hr>
</div>
```